# Is "system in placed" an idiom in English?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

> They have a system in placed to ....
> They have a system in place to ....

I have always used *in placed* without any second thoughts. Someone just pointed out to me that "in placed" is wrong. After a search, it seems that *in place* is indeed correct. May I know the reason from grammatical perspective? What is the term known as so that I can read and learn more about it.

Comment: Prepositions (like "in") are normally followed by nouns, not by the past tense or past participle of a verb (like "placed"). "Place" is a noun. "in place" is an idiom that means something like "in its correct place."

Comment: @JeffreyCarney THANKS!!